# Changing all Cambria Math italic font in an equation to non-italic using Visual Basic in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Regular Find & Replace does nothing. So I am dealing with this program in Visual Basic to run inside MSWord.

Equations in Word use the font `Cambria Math, italic`.

I want to change all equations to `Cambria Math, non-italic (regular)`.

I have this program I found on the web and adapted a little bit.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 17/05/2004 by Tony
'
    Selection.Find.Font.Italic = True
    Selection.Find.Font.Name = "Cambria Math"
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

This finds the text but does not change anything and goes one by one, instead of doing the whole document.

I have also tried this other script, with no luck.

```
Sub ReplaceItalic()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .Font.Name = "Cambria Math"
        .Font.Italic = True

        With .Replacement
            .Font.Italic = False
        End With

        .Execute FindText:="", ReplaceWith:="", _
                 Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that I got it. The problem you were having is that equations are not normal text, but part of an [`OMath` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.omath). So thankfully all that we had to do was loop through all of the `OMath` objects and set their `Range.Font` appropriately!

```
Sub EquationItalics()

    Dim equation As OMath
    For Each equation In ActiveDocument.OMaths
        equation.Range.Font.Italic = False
    Next equation

End Sub
```

Comment: It would appear `equation.ConvertToNormalText` would have same effect.

Comment: @GSerg I wish the documentation would really explain what "normal text" is defined as...

Comment: ah, I have deleted that question. Thanks.